# finding the closed form of $ T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 5n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to use "telescoping" demonstrated in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCS2FFyqNA to solve this recurrence relation.

I started it off below, but quickly lost my way. Might anyone show the process for breaking down this recurrence relation, $ T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 5n$ into a closed form?

$T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 5n $

$T(n-1) = 4T((n-1)/4) + 5n - 5$

$T(n-2) = 4T((n-2)/4) + 5n - 10
$

$....$
$T(n) = ???$

I know we would cancel out the terms on the left and the right side of the $=$ but because it's divided by 4, I'm getting a bit lost...

Thank you

Comment: Is N any integer, or is it any integer div. by 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Taking $m = 4n$

$$
T(4m)=4T(m)+20m
$$

and now

$$
T\left(4^{\log_4(4m)}\right)=4T\left(4^{\log_4(m)}\right)+20m
$$

calling $\mathcal{T}(\cdot)=T(4^{(\cdot)})$ and $z = \log_4 m$

$$
\mathcal{T}(z+1)=4\mathcal{T}(z)+20\times 4^z
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = \left(5z+C_0\right)4^z
$$

now from $z$ to $m$.

Comment: Thank you @Cesareo... I'm a bit confused in how you found $4{^/log(4m)}$ can you explain that part. Thanks!

Comment: With positive $m$ we have $4m=4^{\log_4(4m)}$